# App to support my own language

Tags: android, xml

I want to create Android app to Sinhala   language , but it has not ISO languages codes for android supports.So , i think add font to \assert folder and make **vlues-sin/string.xml** file to my language. how i can select this **vlues-sin/string.xml**  file to when launch the activity!

I goes to do this think!
http://tharindudassanayake.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/use-sinhala-fonts-for-your-android-app/

but I have two xml files.**(value/string.xml & vlues-sin/string.xml)** . User can change app language with in app.

How  can do it?

Comment: According to this list, sinhala is **si**. **vlues-sin/string.xml** won't work (so won't **value/string.xml**). **values-si/string.xml** has a chance to. Here's a tutorial for using custom fonts: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_custom_fonts.htm. To change locale programmatically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2900023/change-language-programatically-in-android.

Comment: @uma: yes it is. The ISO code is `si`, or `sin` in iso-2 and -3 variants. cf wikipedia: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinhala_language